# How to create grid System with col span and row span

Tags: css, grid

I want my CSS grid to have 
1st box "4 col 2 row"
2nd two boxes to be "1 col 1 row" on top of each other then
3rd box to be "1 col  2 row"

[This is how i want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRBCb.png)

Right now when i increase the row span from 1 to 2 of the 3rd box then it moves to left switching its position with the 2nd two boxes

Comment: So we have to guess what isn't working as expected, or you can give us some hints?

Comment: wht posting screenshot of codes ? don't you think it's easier for us to have the real code ?

Comment: @T30  i think we have to first re-write the code from the screenshot then compare to output then guess what is happening

Comment: I think you need to take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site.  If you continue to ask poor quality and downvoted questions, you will get a [question ban](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="grid"</div>
  <div class="box1>1</div>
  <div class="box2>2</div>
  <div class="box3>3</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.grid{
  display:grid;
  width:500px;
  height:500px;
  background-color:beige;
  border:2px solid black;
  grid-template: repeat (3, 1fr) / repeat (3, 1fr);

.box1{
  grid-row: 1 / span 2;
  grid-column: 1 / span 4;

.box2{
  grid-row: 2 / span 1;
  grid-column: 2 / span 1;

.box3{
  grid-row: 3 / span 1;
  grid-column: 3 / span 2;
```

Hope that is what you're asking for.

Comment: First your HTML/CSS is invalid (better verify before posting) and second it's better to avoid replying to such broad question unless the OP provides more info and create a well structured question. By answering you will encourage people to post such questions again and again which is bad for the site.

Comment: You should also post explanation as to what you have done, not just a code dump.  And as you are using css grids, you should mention that it is experimental and doesn't work in all browsers